# Gruntjs concat & minify | Option to replace the code in destination file instead of appending

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Throughout the course of my project development I wish to combine JS and CSS files into *global.js* and *global.css* files and then minify them into *global.min.js* and *global.min.css* using [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) and use these minified files in my project.

But everytime I run the commands it cancats/combines the files and *adds* the combined codes to the global files(Causing redundancy) instead of *replacing* those global files with the new combined codes. Is there any option for it or any other plugin to prevent that?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// 1. All configuration goes here 
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {   
        dist: {
            src: [
                'js/**/*.js',
                'js/*.js'
            ],
            dest: 'js/global.js',
        }
    },


    uglify: {
        build: {
            src: 'js/global.js',
            dest: 'js/global.min.js'
        }
    },

    cssmin: {
      combine: {
        files: {
          'css/global.css': ['css/*.css','css/**/*.css']
        }
      },

       minify: {
        src: 'css/global.css',
        dest: 'css/global.min.css'
      }
    },     


});

// 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

// 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);

};
```

Comment: Can you generate the combined and minified files in a separate directory to the files that they are made up from?

Comment: @LukeWoodward, oops! that must be it :D! Lemme do that!

Comment: @LukeWoodward, yes that was it, Thanks and a happy new year!!!

Comment: Glad that helped.  I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the combined and minified files in a separate directory to the files that they are made up from.

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: @Andypandy: if the generated output file is written to the same directory as the source files, then the next time you run `concat`, it will get `concat`ted with all of the files that make it up.  If you keep running grunt several times, the generated output file will get larger and larger as it includes more and more copies of itself.